# How to rename raster with same names and order of the training data in model in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, raster, caret

I need to raster stack layers (Ras) to be in the **same order** as the training data from a rf model called rfcaret_1000. This is what I have tried:

```
#get order of names in model (rfcaret1000)
name <- rfcaret_1000$ptype

#apply that list of names to stack of rasters (Ras)    
Ras1 <- Ras[[name]]
```

results in this error: Error in .local(x, ...) : not a valid subset

The order of the stack is different than the order of the model names and they need to be the same to predict onto the stack. Here are the names:

```
names(Ras)
"Age"        "DO2"        "DO5"        "Drainage"  
"HSG"        "Irrig1960"  "Irrig1975"  "Irrig1990" 
"Irrig2005"  "LU1945"     "LU1960"     "LU1975"    
"LU1990"     "LU2005"     "NO3_180"    "NO3_400"   
"Precip1960" "Precip1975" "Precip1990" "Precip2005"

 name (from the model)
 Age        Drainage   HSG        LU2005     LU1990    
 LU1975     LU1960     LU1945     NO3_180    NO3_400   
 DO5        DO2        Precip2005 Precip1990 Precip1975
 Precip1960 Irrig2005  Irrig1990  Irrig1975  Irrig1960
```

Comment: Please provide an example with `dput` to know how xgb_train_1 is structured.

Comment: When I use dput() on the model the output is pages and pages long and dput(head()) does not work.

Comment: I guess there is an error related to your variable 'name'. The sorting should work if 'name' contains strings that are layernames of your rasterstack (e.g. name = c("Age", "Drainage", ....) If there is one invalid layername in your 'name' then this error should occur. You can also test this with a for loop: for (n in name) { print(n %in% names(Ras)) } - if FALSE is printed then something with 'name' is wrong.